# Capture image from camera not working on Android 10 OS

Tags: java, android, android-10.0

I have previously implemented in android app to capture an image that is working perfectly till Android 9 OS but suddenly stop working on Android 10 OS.
if anyone else facing the same issue of this please come up.

```
// open the camera from the user's phone
private void takePhotoFromCamera() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA);
}
```

```
// this code is writen in onActivityResult 
if (requestCode == CAMERA) {
    myProfileImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    myImage.setImageBitmap(myProfileImage);
}
```

Comment: _"suddenly stop working on Android 10"_ How exactly? Does the `Intent` still work and opens the camera? Is the problem not getting anything in the `data` intent extra?

Comment: exactly you are wight camera is opening by intent but when I select captured image then there is nothing found in data intent extra.

Comment: The image in `data` is a small snapshot anyway, but apparently it was enough for your use case. The `data` can be problematic even before Android 10 as it might just be `null` in some devices but contain a bitmap in others. I don't know why Android 10 would affect it. Maybe you just tried on a different device(?) Anyway, it's better to not rely on `data`, but instead save the full image and then get it that way [as they describe in the Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics). It's just a little more hassle. :/

Comment: well I have tried on google pixel (with Android 10 OS) and capture image functionality is not working (data is 'null' on 'onActivityResult' method). On the rest of other devices, this functionality is working perfectly fine.

Comment: `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is tied much more closely to the camera app than it is the OS version. There are hundreds of possible camera apps that will wind up taking the picture, and many of those camera apps have bugs.